Docker container having problems connecting to host machine process
everybody; I am trying to access my Jolokia process on my host machine in my telegram.conf file, but my telegraf can't access the process on my host machine.
This is my docker-compose
version: "3"

services:
  atom:
    image: boomi/atom:5.0.2-rhel
    container_name: eyer-observability
    platform: linux/amd64
    volumes:
      - /Users/amarachiiheanacho/Documents/boomi-atom/data:/mnt/boomi:Z
    environment:
      - BOOMI_ATOMNAME=eyer-observability
      - INSTALL_TOKEN=token
      - BOOMI_ENVIRONMENTID=id
      - ATOM_LOCALHOSTID=eyer-observability
    ports: 
      - "9091:9090"
    network_mode: host

  telegraf:
    image: telegraf:latest  # Use the official Telegraf image
    container_name: telegraf
    volumes:
      - /Users/amarachiiheanacho/Documents/boomi-atom/telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:ro  # Mount your Telegraf configuration file (replace with the actual file path)
      - /Users/amarachiiheanacho/Documents/boomi-atom/metrics.out:/metrics.out
    ports:
      - "8086:8086"
    network_mode: host

f i run curl the process on my terminal, i get this response
curl http://localhost:8080/jolokia/
{"request":{"type":"version"},"value":{"agent":"2.0.2","protocol":"7.3","details":{"agent_version":"2.0.2","agent_id":"172.20.10.2-23612-2bfb583b-servlet","server_product":"jetty","server_vendor":"Eclipse","server_version":"12.0.8","secured":false,"url":"http:\/\/172.20.10.2:8080\/jolokia"},"id":"172.20.10.2-23612-2bfb583b-servlet","config":{"maxDepth":"15","discoveryEnabled":"false","agentId":"172.20.10.2-23612-2bfb583b-servlet","maxCollectionSize":"0","debug":"false","canonicalNaming":"true","historyMaxEntries":"10","serializeException":"false","includeStackTrace":"false","maxObjects":"0","detectorOptions":"{}","debugMaxEntries":"100"},"info":{"proxy":{},"jmx":{}}},"status":200,"timestamp":1713470321}%",

if I curl in telegraf
curl http://localhost:8080/jolokia/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 4 ms: Couldn't connect to server

Also how do I connect to the docker atom running

network_mode: host doesn't work reliably on Docker Desktop and other VM-based setups.  Are you running the Docker engine directly on a native-Linux host, or do you have some other setup?  Host networking typically isn't a best practice regardless; does From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine? suggest a useful alternative?

Localhost would refer to the container itself. You shouldn't need host networking to access host.docker.internal:8080

You connect to other containers using their service hostnames
